# Different objects with the same key in a HashMap, move all to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I created a post earlier today but it got marked as DUPLICATE and even after my edit I got no response on it. So I'll be trying to be more specific about just my problem..

**info about my class**

I've a class called Place which extends a class I call Position which is like the class Point, it has x and y coordinates.
And now I create new classes which extends Place, called NamedPlace and DescPlace, it's not much that differ them, just that DescPlace have a description and NamedPlace doesn't..

**My problem**

I need to create a HashMap that where I can put my created objects into. I tried a hashMap like this `HashMap<String, Place> placeMap = new HashMap<>();`
This one works fine, but this is gonna be problem when I create a new NamedPlace called *Pizza Resturant* and later on I add another place called *Pizza Resturant*. Now I've two different objects with the same key in my HashMap

**What i want to do**

I've a searchfield where I enter the name, which is the key for my HashMap, and add ALL those object with that name to an ArrayList where I can't go through those objects one by one and change stuff. Like I've done here, but here I use just one arrayList to all, I need to have a HashMap that stores all objects and which I do the search in..

```
    class SearchLis implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave){
        for(int x = 0; x<placeList.size(); x++){
            if(placeList.get(x).getHighlighted()==true){
                placeList.get(x).setHighlighted(false);
            }
        }
        String search = searchField.getText();
        for(int i = 0; i<placeList.size(); i++){
            if(placeList.get(i).getName().equals(search)){
                placeList.get(i).setHighlighted(true);
                mp.repaint();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, use a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Place>>`.

Comment: Why not `Map<String,List<Place>>` ??

Comment: This is still a duplicate. If you have issues understanding the changes that the use of `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Place>>` involve, post that question. In fact, you should have posted the original question (as it is currently edited) instead of insisting in the original wording.

Comment: Also, give some time to the moderation system to work to find if it reopens your original question after the edit.

Comment: I get these errors with those `The method put(String, List<Place>) in the type Map<String,List<Place>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
 NamedPlace)` @Mena @Sercan

Comment: @FilipBlom that's likely because you are `put`ting a `String` key with value `? extends Place`, instead of `ArrayList<Place>`. Instead, check for `null` on `get`ting the key (if so, `put` an empty `ArrayList<Place>`), then `get` the key and `add` a `Place`.